# Double quotes in string value

Tags: go, terraform

I apologize in advance as I'm just starting with go and trying to write a terraform provider, so I may be missing obvious things.

I was able to fix the problem by removing the double quotes from `databaseId` but I don't understand how it got there in the first place. `c.HostURL` does not have this same problem.

```golang
func (c *Client) GetDatabase(databaseId string) (*Database, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("%s/v1/databases/%s", c.HostURL, strings.Trim(databaseId, "\"")), nil)
    ...
```

Here are what I think are the relevant pieces for the source of databaseId

```golang
type DatabaseDataSourceModel struct {
    Id   types.String `tfsdk:"id"`
    Name types.String `tfsdk:"name"`
}

func (d *DatabaseDataSource) Schema(ctx context.Context, req datasource.SchemaRequest, resp *datasource.SchemaResponse) {
    resp.Schema = schema.Schema{
        MarkdownDescription: "Database data source",

        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
            "id": schema.StringAttribute{
                MarkdownDescription: "Database id",
                Required:            true,
            },
            "name": schema.StringAttribute{
                MarkdownDescription: "Name of the database connection",
                Computed:            true,
            },
        },
    }
}
```

This is how I call GetDatabase

```golang
func (d *DatabaseDataSource) Read(ctx context.Context, req datasource.ReadRequest, resp *datasource.ReadResponse) {
    var data DatabaseDataSourceModel
    ...
    database, err := d.client.GetDatabase(data.Id.String())
```

Is there a way to not have to use `Trim` to remove the quotes or is this expected?

Comment: From [the docs](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/blob/7f6bef5d8aceef2ed775a75515cee6c8614b9191/types/basetypes/string_value.go#L156): "`String` returns a human-readable representation of the String value. Use the `ValueString` method for Terraform data handling instead."

Answer (score 0):

Per isaactfa's comment, I just needed to use `.ValueString()` instead

```golang
database, err := d.client.GetDatabase(data.Id.ValueString())
```